# UITableView Reload Not Updating the tableview with DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I have written code with swift4 and running on iPhone simulator.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.view.activityindicatorStop()
     self.mytableView.reloadData()
}
```

Above code has following operation

Stoping Activity indicator and update `TableView` after data filling with array..

But expected does not happen..

I got following

1. Activity indicator stoped but indicator not 
   removed and background view not removed.
2. `TableView` not updated.

code i have used:

```
 super.viewDidLoad()


        UserDefaults.lastAccessDate = Date()


        self.view.activityStartAnimating(activityColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9176470588, green: 0.2901960784, blue: 0.262745098, alpha: 1), backgroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0))

       //Calling the API  
      Capsulle.retriveSpaceTimeCapsulle { (data, respose, error) in
        if nil == error
        {
         let ServerData = serverComm.toJSONObject(with: data!)
         let result = ServerData.0 as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>
         self.capsulleDetail = result

        if (result == nil)
        {
            if false ==  loginCredential.isHavingAccessToken
            {
            loginCredential.isHavingAccessToken = false;
            UserDefaults.standard.set( "", forKey: "UserEmailID")
            let objStoryBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController:UIViewController = objStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC")

            self.present(initialViewController, animated: true, completion: {

            })

            return
            }
        }


         DispatchQueue.main.sync {

            self.CapsulleCollectionView.reloadData()

            self.view.activityStopAnimating()

         }
         }

      }

    }

func activityStartAnimating(activityColor: UIColor, backgroundColor: UIColor) {
        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height)
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        backgroundView.tag = 475647

        var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        activityIndicator.center = self.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        activityIndicator.color = activityColor
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        backgroundView.addSubview(activityIndicator)

        self.addSubview(backgroundView)
    }

func activityStopAnimating() {
    if let background = self.viewWithTag(475647){

        background.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

i have created activityStopAnimating and activityStartAnimating  as extensions

Comment: Add breakpoint and check once again the code has not issue, it might be of linking tableview and delegate and UITableViewDataSource.

Comment: @GameLoading code does not having issues .after reloading there is no update ..but if i touch or scroll any in the screen the screen shows update..

Comment: Why do you use DispatchQueue.main.sync () ? Can you try without ?

Comment: can you add cell.layoutsubivews in cellforrowatindexpath method

Comment: @GregoryMolette if i am not using means ..it will show error related to main thread warning

Comment: Make sure that the data for tableView are really downloaded an properly set (using debugging is the best option I believe). Otherwise `tableView.reloadData()` won't have any effect. Considering the activityIndicator not being hidden, I would just keep a reference to it rather than using `tag`. Anyways, from how you describe it, it seems that there is a chance that that method does not even get called. Make sure that `activityStopAnimating` gets called (breakpoint or a print statement)

Comment: @abdulsathar have you connected datasource and delegate of UITableView with class ? I am sorry but sometimes we missed the minor one which cause the issue

Comment: @abdulsathar Ensure that the code you have mentioned is getting executed. It won't for the following condition `result == nil` and `false ==  loginCredential.isHavingAccessToken`

Comment: first of all - capturins self in closures is a retain cycle. try ` weak wealSelf = self`
and inside the closure of dispatchMainQUeue - check if weakSelf  is not nil

Answer (score 1):

**For tableView to reload** you have to make sure that `self.capsulleDetail`  have data  changed if this array is your data source
i think it not changed or still zero so reloadData()  will do nothing

**To hide indicator** you should set this property to hide it when stop or hide it directly by sting is-hidden to true

```
self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171528/discussion-between-abdul-sathar-and-abdelahad-darwish).

Answer (score 0):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.view.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    self.view.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
    self.mytableView.beginUpdates()
    self.mytableView.endUpdates()
}
```

your code should work for `tableView` reload but you can also try using `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` method. and to stopActivityindicator call `stopAnimating()` and then hide your activityindicator this code should work for you

Enjoy coding.

Comment: it will send exceptions... actually begin and end update used for insert or delete right?

Comment: yes you are right it is used when we insert or delete but you when we call begin and endupdate it re-excecute all the tableview methods so your data will be reloaded and i think you should try this may be it will work for you.

Answer (score -2):

I don't Find any correct solutions to do this perfectly..

after long run i decided to do following and it is working some what i expect..

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // now update UI on main thread

                        self.myTableView.reloadData()
                        self.myTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -1), animated: true)
                        self.view.activityStopAnimating()

                    }
```

Thanks for all of your answers..i am awaiting for perfect answer..